# I cannot give full access to the user in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I try to run the demo of the Broadleaf framework with a Tomcat server. I get a

> HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

I saw on this website that it has to do with permissions and I want to give full access to SYSTEM and User, so right click on the `Tomcat map -> properties -> security -> edit` and I check full access.

I apply and click ok, while I do that the full access check disappears. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I doubt it has to do with permissions, there is probably a lib missing, which prevents the index.jsp from being processed to a class. Does the Tomcat-manager-app work (`localhost:8080/manager/`)?

Answer (score 0):

Above error is not due to permission. Sometimes jsp not compiled automatic that's why we get the above error message. Make sure tomcat is running also you application id fully deployed on server. Clean and build your project and again try to access. Still any issue paste all you tomcat logs.